# Как добавить страницу уже в готовый сайт -ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Всем добрый день, 
Коллеги кто сталкивался с такой проблемой. 
Есть готовый сайт, исходный код утерян. 
Но нужно добавить новый раздел. Понятно что простое добавление папки со страницами в Views не помогает.
Кто знает где можно уже на сервере ISS прописать путь и можно ли это сделать в принципе.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если надо добавить статическую страницу - добавляйте ее куда угодно, кроме папки Views.

Views - это папка для видов, возвращаемых как результат выполнения действий контроллеров. Эти виды не предназанчены для "прямого выполнения". Поэтому во Views лежит web.config в котором написано следующее:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

что выдает 404 на любое прямое обращение к любым файлам, даже если это просто html-страницы.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что прописать руками еще одно представление  уже в готовый сайт не получится?

Comment: @blakcat представление добавить можно - просто закинуть файл во Views. Но вам нужно добавить еще и действие - метод контроллера - который это представление покажет. А контроллер вы исправить не можете. Максимум что можно сделать - попробовать добавить новый контроллер (в отдельной dll). И найти способ его вызвать. Если роуты у вас прописаны аккуратно - то вам не повезло. А если неаккуратно, и у вас прописан стандартный {controller}/{action} - то достаточно просто угадать с неймспейсом и именем класса для нового контроллера.

Comment: Извени, может быть за несколько глупый вопрос. А куда в конечном итоги компилица контролер. И да роуты стандартные. Каким образом угадывается неймспейс.

Comment: @blakcat Неймспейс - посмотреть у существующих контроллеров. Контроллер скомпилить в dll, подкинуть ее в bin, и прописать в вебконфиге в compilation/assemblies.

Comment: Я правильно понял что в этом случае я просто подменю одно из уже существующих представлений?

Comment: @blakcat нет, вы добавите новый контроллер (который будет попадать под стандартный роут). и который вернет результат, который отрендерит нужное представление. "подменить" существующее действие не получится. максимум - исправить его представление.